# how to connect mysql server using c?

Tags: mysql

how to connect mysql server using c?

Any article related this?

Comment: Well, there's all the mysql client library documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd result from Google:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html